# Does any database track all inserts, updates, deletes so that you can simply undo any changes until you get back to a good state?

Tags: rollback

Sometimes people make inserts, updates, or deletes they did not intend to and want to revert back their changes (or undo them).  Are there databases out there that make this easy to do (i.e. are there database that track every single insert, update, delete ever made to it so that you can recreate the entire database up until a certain time)?

Comment: @J.D.  - ok thanks . If you answer this question I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there database that track every single insert, update, delete **ever** made to it so that you can recreate the entire database up until a certain time

I know of no database system that offers this out of the box - for a specific set of changes. Doing so would be extremely difficult, as multiple changes can be compounded on previous changes or the state of the data as the result of previous changes, at different points in time, across multiple tables. So it's not as simple as undoing the linear list of changes to a single table, which would otherwise break the [ACID principles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of a database system. But, point in time recovery is possible, to consistently restore the database as a whole, to a previous state at a certain time (discussed further at the end of this answer).

Some database systems offer forms of change tracking for data auditing purposes. For example, Microsoft SQL Server has the features [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), and [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) which keep track of data changes in supplemental tables, with information such as the old values and the timestamps of when the change occurred. This is for manual reconciliation and auditing, but not a tool to completely undo the state of the database in totality, to a certain previous point in time.

The closest one could get to that would be using granular backups, such as the [Transaction Log Backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/transaction-log-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) that SQL Server offers, which will restore the database back to a certain point in time, but not undo a specific set of changes to only certain tables. It's a completely consistent restore of the database, in it's entirety, to a specific point in time.

Answer (score 2):

> ... inserts, updates, or deletes they did not intend to and want to revert back their changes (or undo them).

That's what **Transactions** are for.

You start a Transaction, make some changes, decide you don't want them any more and rollback to the start of that Transaction, throwing away those changes.
Depending on your DBMS, no-one else will have any idea that it ever happened.

Our most most common use for this is to protect ourselves against the "Oops Moment":

```
begin transaction ;                  -- this bit is DBMS-specific 

update the_banks_10million_accounts 
set account_balance = 0 ;            -- OOPS! 

rollback ;                           -- No harm done
```

> Are there databases ... that track every single insert, update, delete ever made to it so that you can recreate the entire database up until a certain time)?

Yes.  Just about **all** of them.

What you're describing is generally called a "**Point in Time Recovery**" and it's an absolutely *essential* tool for the DBA.

- At such and such a time, "Something Bad(TM)" happens in the database.
- You need to take the *whole* database back to [just before] that point in time to make it as if "Something Bad(TM)" never happened.

To perform a Point in Time Recovery, you restore a previous [Full] backup and then "roll-forward" [Interim Backups and] Transaction Logs to get back to the Point in Time required.

Sounds *great*, doesn't it?

Now, the $64,000 question:

> Why don't DBMS's make this *easy*?

Because, paradoxically, this "Point in Time Recovery" process is **destructive**.

Say "Something Bad(TM)" happens as 12 noon.
*Some part* of the database is broken and *some things* stop working.
It might take an hour or so before word reaches you and you have to "fix" the database.
During that hour, lots of *other* stuff has been happening in the database that "Something Bad(TM)" *didn't* break.  All of those other changes will be **destroyed** by this recovery process.

Why?
Because recovering a database *isn't* like getting into your Delorean and flying back to 1955 (although Oracle Database's "Flashback Query" *does* offer something very much like this).
Once it's been recovered, your database will be *as it was* "back in 1955", with *no knowledge* of anything that's happened since then.  All that lovely work that people did from 12 noon until your started the recovery will be *gone*.

The only way around that is to recover a *copy* of the database, extract the "broken" data as it was before "Something Bad(TM)" happened and then figure out how to "shoe-horn" that data back into the *original* database, replacing the broken data.  That can be very, very painful and time-consuming and actually cause more problems as it solves.